# Current location through SIM Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Through Telephony Manager or SIM in my mobile/device, i need to get my location, I tried posting cell id, location code which i get from telephony manager to "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap" and receive data, but it always returns null data,
did anyone try this and received positive data, Please help !

Thanks

Comment: see this question - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888151/android-get-location-from-cell-tower)